# How to solve for the complex number $z$?

Tags: complex-numbers

How to solve for the complex number $z$?
$$z^6=(z-1)^6$$

Comment: You can literally go to WolframAlpha and type this *exact* question in, and you won't even have to wait for a real human to answer.  Please improve the question with your own thoughts and efforts: This is not Yahoo! answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Big Hint**

$$...\iff \left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^6=1\iff \frac{z}{z-1}=e^{\frac{ik\pi}{3}}$$
where $k=1,...,5$. I let you continue.

Comment: Why did this get a down vote??  I'll neutralize it.  +1 -Mark

Comment: I didn't downvote, but looking at your answer I see one possible issue. Isn't $k=0$ problematic here since $z$ can't equal $z-1$?

Comment: @Dr.MV I suspect that someone downvoted this because they don't like answer that encourage questions of this quality.

Comment: @spencer I hadn't noticed the $k=0$.  Yes, Surb, this is a 5th order polynomial in $z$, and has only 5 roots.  - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why $k=0$ doesn't work. I see it doesn't work, but I don't understand why. It looks to be a subtle trap.

Comment: @user301068 There are $6$ roots of $w^6=1$.  But, if $w=z/(z-1)$, there are corresponfing values of $z$ for only $5$ of those roots.

Comment: @Dr.MV: So in theory we have to check by hand that the $\frac{z}{z-1}=e^{i k\pi/3}$ for the other $k$ has really sense, don't we ? (i.e. that for any $k\in\{1,...,5\}$, $\frac{z}{z-1}=e^{ik\pi/3}$ has sense) or is it obvious ? Because here I would never imagine that it can't work.

Comment: @user30168 Not really.  Solve for $z$ with $k$ as an index.  You will find that there is a singularity for $k=0$ only.  All other values are fine.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Set $\;u=\dfrac z{z-1}\;$ and solve for $u^6=1$, then go back to $\;z=\dfrac u{u-1}$ .

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $z^6 - (z-1)^6 = 0 \Rightarrow (z^3-(z-1)^3)(z^3 + (z-1)^3) = 0\Rightarrow (z-(z-1))(z^2 +z(z-1)+ (z-1)^2)(z+(z-1))(z^2-z(z-1)+(z-1)^2)=0$