# Mistake in raising power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find roots of:
$$x^{6}\ -\ \left(x-1\right)^{6}=0 \tag {1}$$

I know this equation has $4$ complex roots and exactly one real roots of value $0.5$.

However, my first instinct was to do this:
$$x^{6}\ =\ \left(x-1\right)^{6} \tag{2}$$
"raise both sides to 6-th power" to get:
$$x=x-1\tag{3}$$

Which has no real solution. I see that this wrong. How to avoid this error? Thanks.

Inspired by watching [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jENiRqdk3s)

**Edit:**

I am not asking about how to solve the problem. I want to know
what I did wrong from an Algebraic stand-point. Maybe raising to the power? What is wrong with that?

Comment: You meant "raise both sides to the $1/6$ power". Since $6$ is even, for $x$ real it is $x^6=(x-1)^6 \iff |x|=|x-1|$.

Comment: @NoChance Note that $x^6 - (x-1)^6 = 0$ is a polynomial of degree $5$ (since the $x^6$ terms cancel each other), so if there's $4$ complex roots, there can only be $1$ real root, with $x = 0.5$ being it (coming from $|x| = |x-1|$ mentioned in Bernkastel's comment).

Comment: @Bernkastel, you are correct, I edited the quesion.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, you are correct. Good point. I will edit the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve for the complex number $z$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629767/how-to-solve-for-the-complex-number-z)

Comment: You can find the real roots by factoring methods: $$x^6 - (x - 1)^6  \\  = \left(x^3\right)^2 - \left((x-1)^3\right)^2 \\ = \left(x^3 + (x - 1)^3 \right) \cdot \left(x^3 - (x - 1)^3\right) \\ =  \left(x^3 + (x - 1)^3 \right) \cdot \left(3x^2 - 3x + 1\right)$$

$3x^2 - 3x + 1$ does not have a real root, but $x^3 + (x - 1)^3 = 0$ does. Now, $a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)$

Comment: @Anne Bauval, thanks for the link. While the link is good, my question is not about how to solve the equation, it is precisely on what I did wrong from an Algebraic stand-point.

Comment: @NoChance Haven't you read the comment of Bernkastel? You've forgotten the absolute value.

Comment: What you did wrong is simply believing $a^6=b^6\implies a=b.$

Comment: To amplify a bit on the comment of @AnneBauval, taking a sixth root (or any even root) in the real numbers is not necessarily a well defined function.  That's because if $x^6=t$, it's necessarily also the case that $(-x)^6=t$ as well.  By convention we usually say that *the* sixth root of a positive number is a positive number, but in a situation like yours, that choice does not exhaust all possibilities and the word *the* shouldn't be used because there are multiple possible sixth roots to consider.

Comment: @callculus42, yes - Looks like I am not aware of the implications of absolute value in this case. Looks like when |x|=|y|, this does not mean that $x=y$ always.

Comment: @RobertShore, that clarifies things more. Thanks.

Comment: $a^2=b^2\iff a=\pm b.$ With $a=x^3$ and $b=(x-1)^3,$ therefore $x^3=\pm (x-1)^3.$  If $c,d\in\Bbb R$ then $c^3=\pm d^3 \iff c=\pm d.$ With $c=x^3$ and $d=(1-x)^3,$ therefore if $x\in\Bbb R$ then $x=\pm (1-x).$ This last formula is equivalent to $x=1/2.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, clear explanation. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had started with $x^2 - (x-1)^2=0$ then you can expand it to $x^2-x^2+2x-1=0$ and so $x=\frac12$.

But let's take a version of your approach. You might say $a^2=b^2$ clearly implies $a=b$ or $a=-b$; let's write this as $a=\omega b$ where $\omega^2=1$.  We expect there to be be two possible values for $\omega$, namely $+1$ and $-1$.  But if $a=x$ and $b=x-1$ you get $x=\omega(x-1)$ and so $x=  \frac{-\omega}{1-\omega}= 1 - \frac{1}{1-\omega}$; when $\omega=-1$ it gives $x=\frac12$ as expected, while if $\omega=1$ it tries to give $1- \frac{1}{0}$ which is not a finite number, reflecting the fact there is no finite solution to $x=x-1$.

Translate this to your $6$th powers in $(2)$:

- $a^6=b^6$ has solutions of the form $a=\omega b$ where $\omega^6=1$;
- there are potentially six such $\omega$ (some complex) of which one is $\omega=1$
- If $a=x$ and $b=x-1$ you get $x=\omega(x-1)$ and again $x=  1 - \frac{1}{1-\omega}$
- So each of the six $\omega$ will give you a different solution for $x$, except $\omega=1$ which tries to give $1-\frac{1}{0}$ (still not a finite number).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a clear explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the posted comments above. At the moment, no one had posted an answer, but I understood the following, which combined may provide an answer.

$$|x|=|x-1|$$

can't always be written as $x=x-1$. I need to learn how to solve such an equation.

Also,
$$a^n=b^n$$

Does not always imply that $a=b$. The result is affected by the domain of $a$ and $b$ and whether the power is even or odd or integer or not, maybe among other factors.

Comment: Note for real $y$ and $z$ that $|y| = |z|$ means $y = z$ or $y = -z$. In your case with $|x| = |x-1|$, since $x \neq x - 1$, then we must instead have $x = -(x - 1) = -x + 1 \; \to \; 2x = 1 \; \to \; x = 0.5$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, excellent explanation. Thank you.